# UITextField no keyboard when seguing to viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a viewController that checks a password ... This is used when the program starts up .. and when changing the old password...

When the app launches I use this to display the view:

```
    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL needsPassCheck = [def boolForKey:kHasPassword];
if (needsPassCheck) {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];

    VerifyPasswordViewController *passC = (VerifyPasswordViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passCheck"];
    passC.loginCheck = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = passC;
}
```

This works well ... In the other case i use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueID"];
```

Here is the problem... In the firs case the keyboard shows up just as planned ... but in the second case it doesn't show at all ... not even if the text field is tapped ...

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    [self.passwordTextField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

I tried without the delay ... no change ... What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your viewDidAppear get called in 2nd case? If it does, I suppose it does appear, and gets suppressed by something else? Also does your view implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol?

Comment: It does get called in the 2nd case... but it doesn't appear... The UITextFieldDelegate is not implemented ... could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, this needs to be implemented in order for responder part to work.

Comment: I added the UITextFieldDelegate ... in the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method I added a NSLog ... It gets called only in the 1st case ...